# Java Regular expression to find out all the columns of a particular table using table alias

Tags: java, regex

In the below query , I need to search for all the columns of the table1 using alias T_1

`select T_1.name, T_1.age, T_2.dept from table1 T_1, table2 T_2 where T_1.id=T_2.id`

**Answer:** *name, age, id*

I am using the below expression, in that i want to end the search when a special character occur. In the below expression I am ending the search when there is "=", but I want to generalize when there is a non aplpha numeric character.

`"(?i)\\b" + T_1 + "\\." + "[a-zA-Z]*([^\\=]+)"`

Regular expression should work for below query also,
select T_1.name, T_1.age from table1 where T_1.id>100

Comment: `"(?i)\\bT_1\\.(\\w+)"`?

Comment: You need a word boundary after the identifier. Don't look for an actual character, but for a word boundary (because it could also be the end of the string - like if you had `WHERE T_2.id=T_1.id`.

Comment: Your `[a-zA-Z]*` was actually enough, this can't match non-alphanumeric characters (or even numeric characters) so it  would have stopped at the `=`, space or comma

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]` cannot be enough to match *aplpha numeric character*. Either `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or `\p{Alnum}` / `[^\W_]` should be used at least

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)\bT_1\.(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UWRidr/1). Note the `\w+` does not match "special" chars, only letters, digits or underscores. If underscores are not allowed, replace `\w+` with `[^\W_]+`, or `\p{Alnum}` and append `\b` word boundary:

```
(?i)\bT_1\.([^\W_]+)\b
```

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insenstivie mode on
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `T_1\.` - `T_1.` substring
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more letters, digits or `_`. To exclude `_` and only match letters or digits, use `([^\W_]+)` or `(\p{Alnum}+)` and append `\b` word boundary.

Java usage:

```
String regex1 = "(?i)\\bT_1\\.(\\w+)";
String regex2 = "(?i)\\bT_1\\.([^\\W_]+)\\b";
```